# What is scrim in collapsibletoolbarlayout?

Tags: android

I read collapsible toolbar layout on developers android. There is a term scrim used there. What is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Scrim:** A thing that conceals or obscures something.

As per Android CollapsingToolbarLayout:

**Content scrim:** A full-bleed scrim which is show or hidden when the scroll position has hit a certain threshold. You can change this via setContentScrim(Drawable).

You can use drawable as a scrim on top of the CollapsingToolbarLayouts content when it has been scrolled sufficiently off screen.

> `app:contentScrim="YOUR_TOOLBAR_COLOR"`

**Status bar scrim:** A scrim which is show or hidden behind the status bar when the scroll position has hit a certain threshold. You can change this via setStatusBarScrim(Drawable). **This only works on LOLLIPOP devices when we set to fit system windows.**

You can use drawable as a scrim for the status bar content when the CollapsingToolbarLayout has been scrolled sufficiently off screen.

> `app:statusBarScrim="YOUR_STATUSBAR_COLOR"`

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the material design docs say:
https://material.io/design/environment/surfaces.html#attributes

> Scrims are temporary treatments that can be applied to Material surfaces for the purpose of making content on a surface less prominent. They help direct user attention to other parts of the screen, away from the surface receiving a scrim.

> Scrims can be applied in a variety of ways, including:

> Darkening or lightening the surface and its content
> Reducing the opacity of the surface and its content
> Multiple surfaces on a screen at a time can display scrims. Scrims can appear at any elevation, whether in the foreground or background.

[image]